# Triangular Mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, subdivision-surface

I have imported an IFC model into Blender for texturing and rendering purpose.

The issue I have is that every geometry comes as triangulated mesh, which means adding different texture onto some part of the same object is impossible because it's impossible to select rectangular area of the mesh.
Also, adding height map is impossible because of the irregular subdivision.
I tried to remesh into a quad one object but there is an issue when the corners are rounded, as seen in the upper object.

Is anyone else facing the same issue when tring to render an imported model into Blender and has found a workaround?[image]

Comment: what is the final object, and what are the materials you're supposed to put?

Comment: @moonboots for exaple a pubble stones in the middle part. I would need  to subdivide that part for in order to add displacement of the stones but because of the irregular geometry, I cant select rectangular area and the subdivision will not be equal throught.

Comment: You can try to subdivide the opposite sides to the same amount and use Grid Fill.